# Topic redirects with addition characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

I really appreciate the help you guys
have been rendering to people.

I am using Pretty URL for SMF.
I want to redirect a topic to another but the URL for the page which the Pretty URL gets the content it displays is attached to the URL after redirection.

Here is an example.
I used this in my `.htaccess`.

> Redirect 301 /2030/ https://google.com

I am just testing, I am trying to redirect `http://example.com/2030` to Google site address.
but when I redirect to Google, the URL contains:

> https://www.google.com/?pretty;board=2030.0

`pretty; board=2030` is the page which the `http://example.com/2030` gets the content it displays.

How can I redirect to `https://www.google.com` without the
`pretty;board=2030` showing.

Here is my entire `.htaccess`

```
# PRETTYURLS MOD BEGINS
# Pretty URLs mod
# http://code.google.com/p/prettyurls/
# .htaccess file generated automatically on: September 1, 2018, 16:50

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /2030 https://google.com
RewriteBase /

# Rules for: profiles
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=profile;user=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: actions
RewriteRule ^(activate|admin|announce|attachapprove|buddy|calendar|clock|collapse)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(coppa|credits|deletemsg|display|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2|emailuser)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(findmember|groups|help|helpadmin|im|jseditor|jsmodify|jsoption)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(lock|lockvoting|login|login2|logout|markasread|mergetopics|mlist)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(moderate|modifycat|modifykarma|movetopic|movetopic2|notify|notifyboard|openidreturn)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(pm|post|post2|printpage|profile|quotefast|quickmod|quickmod2)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(recent|register|register2|reminder|removepoll|removetopic2|reporttm|requestmembers)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(restoretopic|search|search2|sendtopic|smstats|suggest|spellcheck|splittopics)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(stats|sticky|theme|trackip|about:mozilla|about:unknown|unread|unreadreplies)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(verificationcode|viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who|\.xml|xmlhttp)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: boards
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: topics
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;topic=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;topic=$1.$3 [L,QSA]

# PRETTYURLS MOD ENDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Redirect 301 /2030 https://google.com
```

with

```
RewriteRule   "(.)*/2030$"  "https://google.com"  [R=301,L]
```